# Process ends unexpectedly

Tags: .net

I am starting a new process in a .net service and running winrar in console.
It works fine for folders that do not have a large amount of files and individual files, but when archiving big folders the process seems to stop at some point.
I am saying it seems to stop because

1. The archive is not complete when I get the output back
2. The main process triggering the raring of the folder starts again

Here is the piece of code that runs the process:

```
Private Sub log(text As String)
    IO.File.AppendAllText("log.txt", text)
End Sub

Private Sub SortOutputHandler(sendingProcess As Object, _
     outLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) Then
        numOutputLines += 1
        log(Environment.NewLine & "[" _
                     & numOutputLines.ToString() & "] - " _
                     & outLine.Data)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function RunCmd(ParamArray commands As String()) As String
    Try
        If Not sortOutput Is Nothing Then
            sortOutput.Length = 0
        End If

        Dim returnvalue As String = String.Empty

        Dim info As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd")
        info.UseShellExecute = False
        info.RedirectStandardInput = True
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        info.CreateNoWindow = True

        Using process__1 As Process = Process.Start(info)
            AddHandler process__1.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf SortOutputHandler
            process__1.BeginOutputReadLine()

            Using sw As StreamWriter = process__1.StandardInput
                For Each command As String In commands
                    sw.WriteLine("chcp 65001")
                    sw.WriteLine(command)
                    log(command)
                Next
                sw.Close()
            End Using
            process__1.WaitForExit()
        End Using

        returnvalue = sortOutput.ToString

        info = Nothing
        Return returnvalue
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function

Private Sub zip(destinationFolder As String, outputFile As String, sourceItem As String) 
    Dim results As String = RunCmd("rar.exe u """ & destinationFolder & outputFile & """ -m3 -w" & workingDir & " """ & sourceItem & """ ")

End Sub
```

What I get as an output is what one would expect when running rar from the command line but it just ends at some point in the middle of archiving:

```
[3945] - Adding    \\servername\path1      51%  OK 
[3946] - Adding    \\servername\path2      51%
[3947] - C:\Windows\system32>
```

The archive is incomplete and a System.IO. exception is raised in the main block of the service complaining it can't find part of a path (one of the child folders of the source passed to the command line)

I am wondering if the asynchronous read of the output is correct? 
It seems to me it is as I get the output line by line in the log file, but I had the same issue (although couldn't have the same logs) when I was reading the output synchronously.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of the code:

```
Catch ex As Exception
    Return Nothing
End Try
```

Any exception that may occur is just ignored, and the function returns immediately. You could at least return exception message instead of Nothing, which would hopefully give you a hint on what happened, and how to resolve the situation.

Comment: This is a slightly cut down version of the code, there is an additional call in that catch to log the exception. There is no exception in that part of the code essentially, the only exception I get is in the main block of my service that is calling the zip Sub. Since the only reason the main part of the service is being repeated is because the rar doesn't complete in the first place I think it probably has nothing to do with it